# Microsoft Graph Batch Queries: referencing batch dependency fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the "dependsOn" option in Microsoft Graph batch queries, is it possible to reference a field in the dependency query?

For example, to create a team you must provide a group id - "dependsOn" concept seems apt - you create a group prior to the team in your batch query (specified by the "dependsOn" param), but how do you refer the id (or any other field) in the team creation part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately, but that would be great! It only enforces order, and any request dependent on another will fail if the dependency request fails.

You might want to suggest this on [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks - user voice suggestion here: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40248217-field-references-in-batch-queries-with-internal-de